# Google doc api for iphone - conditional fetching with If-None-Match or If-Modified-Since

Tags: objective-c, google-docs-api

I am building Google docs sync application for iPad. I am able to download all the files from Google doc account to iPad for offline viewing. Now I want to optimize the sync process where only updated documents will be downloaded during sync process.

As per the gdoc api reference document, I need to use If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match query parameters for conditional fetching. However, I am not able to understand how to do it?

I tried adding both these parameters while fetching document list. I also tried adding these params while actually downloading each document entry. But its fetching all the documents every time.

If someone has already implemented conditional fetching using Google docs api,

I am using version 2 of Google data api for objective-c

Comment: Hi Suyash, I am dealing with this issue recently, discuss with me. (MSN:zzy_moon@hotmail.com, email:zzymoon@gmail.com).